# why can't i get consistent heights for textboxes and dropdown boxes in internet explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, proxy, height

im using ie8 and my lan connection in it uses a proxy. i can connect to a local server and access my web files in there with or w/o this proxy using an ip url (10.32.16....). *my textboxes and drowpdown boxes are of the same height when the proxy is on*. **but if i dont use the proxy, the dropwdown boxes' height become shorter than that of the textboxes**. what is going on!!? its the same browser but just a disabled proxy

i tried to control the height using css, but it doesnt work when i turn the proxy back on. its like if i have the same height when the proxy is on, i get two different heights when its off. and if i attempt to keep the height consistent when the proxy is off using css, i get the reverse when the proxy is back on -- kind of frustrating. hope you guys can shed a light on this or convince me to just let it pass...aarrgghhh

and also, the same thing happened with my javascript functions, they work fine if the proxy is on but not if its off. however, i have fixed this by rewriting them to a simpler version. just couldnt do it with the html elements i mentioned. this really baffles me. thnx.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your external CSS and JS files are being served correctly when the proxy is on?

Does the same happen if you embed the CSS within the html document?

Answer (score 0):

Enabling the proxy is probably changing the "Zone" IE is assigning to your server. IE8 switches to compatibility rendering mode (IE7 mode) automatically for certain zones (Local Intranet, for example)